# ssh config: global settings vs `Host *`

Tags: ssh, configuration

What is the difference between ssh configuration file settings:

- At the top (global) level
- In a `Host *` scope?

Assuming there is a difference, in which cases would each be preferred?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [SSH configuration documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) touches on this indirectly:

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. The configuration files contain sections separated by **Host** specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification.

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

So settings in the “top” level can’t be overridden, whereas settings in `Host *` will be overridden by any setting defined before that section (in the “top” level, or in a section matching the target host).

This answers “in which cases would each be preferred”: the “top” level should be used for settings which shouldn’t be overridden, and the `Host *` section, which should come last, should be used for default settings.

Comment: Does your answer effectively say "there's no difference except for hinting at please-don't-override-me settings"? (Unless`shouldn’t be overridden` means `can't be overridden`)?

Comment: Right, my answer wasn’t quite clear enough; the top level should be used for settings which shouldn’t be overridden, because the top level settings can’t be overridden.